# How do I configure LuaRocks to install packages for 5.2 instead of 5.1?

Tags: lua, package-managers, luarocks

LuaRocks seems to assume 5.1 by default, how do I specify that I am using 5.2? Installed modules are installed in a 5.1 directory, and as such, Lua 5.2 can't find them.

Comment: Do you have a `luarocks-5.2` "binary"? Does running `lua5.2 /path/to/luarocks` run it with 5.2 paths/etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the best way to do this is to build from source. Essentially, all you need to do is run

```
./configure --lua-version=5.2
```

in the directory of the luarocks code, and then make build and then make install and you should be good to go